# Spectrum of an element of a Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis

For a Banach algebra $A$ and $a \in A ,$ $\sigma(a)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \lambda -a \text{ is not invertible in  } A \}.$
I need to show that $\sigma(\alpha a) =\alpha \sigma(a)$ in order for me to complete the problem I am working on. Could someone please help me on how I can go about this.

I know that $\sigma(a)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \lambda -a \text{ is not invertible in  } A \}$ and that  $ \sigma(\alpha a)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \lambda -\alpha a \text{ is not invertible in  } A \}= \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \alpha(\lambda/\alpha - a )\text{ is not invertible in  } A \} .$

Comment: For $\alpha\neq 0$, you have $a \text{ invertible} \iff (\alpha a) \text{ invertible}$.

Answer (score 1):

may be helpful to think of a finite-dimensional analogue where the eigenvalues of a matrix are scaled when the matrix itself is multiplied by a scalar, here because $(| \alpha |\ne 0)$:
$$
|M-\lambda I| = 0 \iff |\alpha M - \alpha \lambda I| = 0
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Fischer and Holden. Am now getting something of interest. Once more thanx a lot.